# Lagrange Multiplier Question and my attempt

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier

Question is "Find the extrema of $xyz$ when $x+y+z=a$, $a>0$".

Starting with usual Lagrange Multiplier method, I get

$f_x = yz + \lambda = 0$

$f_y = xz + \lambda = 0$

$f_z = yz + \lambda = 0$

Now from three equations above, I multiply first by $x$ and second by $y$ and third by $z$, I get

$f_x = xyz + \lambda x = 0$

$f_y = xyz + \lambda y = 0$

$f_z = xyz + \lambda z = 0$

Clearly from these equating values of $xyz$. I get $x=y=z$. And thus I have solved the question and is consistent with my answer with textbook.

BUT, if I manipulate equations in a way as if I equate values of $\lambda$ I get

$yz=xz=xy$

Now I take $yz=xz$. This implies either $z=0$ or $x=y$.

If I take $z=0$ and put in other two equations I get $xy=0$ which means either $x=0$ or $y=0$. Say I take $x=0$ and now putting in constraint equation I get $y=a$ so i get $(0,a,0)$. Not only this but by solving other equations like this I get $(0,a,0)$, $(a,0,0)$, $(0,0,a)$, $((a-1)/2,(a-1)/2,1)$.
But this is not consistent with textbook.

Can anybody help me out from here? Thanks

Comment: Your working and answers look good to me.  I suggest you carefully check the question in the book.  It may have stated that $x,y,z,a$ are all positive (or something similar).  Then the solutions $x=0$ etc would not be valid.  In this case $xyz$ would have no minimum, because it can be as close as you like to zero but can never equal zero.

Comment: @David they have said $a > 0$

Comment: If $x,y,z$ are allowed to be negative then $xyz$ can be as large as you like in the negative direction and so there is no minimum.  You should check the possibilities $x=0$ etc (as you have done) but in this case they do not give maximum or minimum values.  Remember that solving the Lagrange equations gives *possible* extreme points, but some of them may in fact turn out to be not extreme points.

Comment: @David .then wat about $((a−1)/2, (a−1)/2, 1)$ . The correct answer is at $(a/3,a/3/a/3)$ which i have found by my former manipulation of equations . but that  is fine .Out of 4 points i have obtained the first three gives $f=0$ .so they can also be ruled out because of $(a/3,a/3/a/3)$ (it gives $a^{3}/27$) .

Comment: @David Wit that first three points can be minima ? im getting confused

Comment: Sorry, I missed that, $((a−1)/2,(a−1)/2,1)$ is not a solution because it doesn't satisfy $xy=yz=zx$.  (Except for special values of $a$ in which case it reduces to your other solutions.)

Comment: @David Why cant be $(a,0,0)$ be minima point giving $f=0$

Comment: The value $f=0$ is not a minimum because for example $x=a,\,y=1,\,z=-1$ gives $f=-a$ which is smaller.

Comment: @David But that ain't critical point.

Comment: Doesn't matter, you are looking for maximum and minimum values, and if $f$ can be negative then $0$ isn't a minimum.

Comment: @David Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There must be some constraints on $x,y,z$

Without using Lagrange Multiplier

Assuming $x,y,z\gt0$

Using AM-GM

$$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$

$$x+y+z=a\ge3\sqrt[3]{xyz}$$
$$\frac{a^3}{27}\ge xyz$$
and equality occurs when $x=y=z$

Comment: this is another approach .thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have derived the correct result with the Lagrange Multiplier method:

$xy = yz = zx = -\lambda$

Here $\lambda$ is a non-zero parameter. From this it follows that $x, y$ and $z$ can not be zero. The only solution is $x = y = z = \sqrt{-\lambda}$. And therefore $x = y = z = a/3$.

Comment: i see . thankss